# What is the purpose of ASP.NET's machine key validation key

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET 4, the [default hashing algorithm was changed to HMACSHA256](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770148). I know the decryption key is used in forms authentication and for the new ASP.NET Identity cookie authentication. Is the validation key used for anything other than Viewstate validation in Web Forms?

Reason I ask is that we use static machine keys in a number of applications and they are still using SHA1 for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the validation key used for anything other than Viewstate validation in Web Forms?

In addition to that, I believe it also affects the behavior of the [`MachineKey.Protect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx) function, and corresponding Unprotect function. This API allows developers to protect arbitrary values. The MVC Framework [makes use of this](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/MachineKeyWrapper.cs#L26) for Anti-Forgery tokens, so changing the validation key will affect CSRF token generation and validation.

Comment: For what it is worth, since CSRF and ViewState values are short lived, neither of these should stop you from changing to HMACSHA256.